# Why I cannot insert IgnoreQueryFilters() into my IQueryable method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Task:

```
 public async Task<List<Event>> GetDeletedDocumentsAsync()
 {
    return await GetDocumentsAsync()
      .Deleted()
      .IgnoreQueryFilters()
      .ToListAsync();
 }
```

And my extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Deleted<T>(this IQueryable<T> source) where T : IDeleted
{
    return source.Where(d => d.DeletedAt!= null);
}

private IQueryable<Event> GetDocumentsAsync() 
{ 
   _context.Documents 
   .AsNoTracking() 
   .AsQueryable(); 
}
```

I would like to relocate .IgnoreQueryFilters() into Deleted() but it says:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IgnoreQueryFilters(IQueryable)